# Android audio level meter

Tags: java, android, audio, stream

I got a question I hope you can help with, I have searched but had no luck yet. Basically I have made a few ios apps and a couple android but I'm still learning the basics of java and android etc. I have radio streaming apps and have audio level bars on the ios versions, I want to put these on the android versions but can't work out the code to have a left and right bar for sound. Any ideas where to learn some code and also so it stretches from left of screen to right but for all screen sizes? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout the [`Visualizer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html) class. It should provide you with what you need to display a level meter. Unfortunately, it is only available in API 9 and higher and requires the RECORD_AUDIO permission.